# Prove that this matrix equation has no roots if a matrix meets certain conditions

Tags: matrices

Could you explain to me how to solve matrix equations?

Here is an example:

Prove that:

$$2X^2 + X = \begin{bmatrix} -1&5&3\\-2&1&2\\0&-4&-3\end{bmatrix}$$

has no solutions in $M(3,3;\mathbb{R})$, where $M(3,3;\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all $3\times3$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: For clarity, do you mean $X$ instead of $x$ to represent a matrix as opposed to a variable? Regards

Comment: Yes, I meant a matrix. It's already corrected.

Answer (score 3):

First note that $X$ is a $3\times 3$ real matrix and hence it must have at least one real eigenvalue.

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1&5&3\\-2&1&2\\0&-4&-3\end{pmatrix}$$
which is $$p(\lambda) = -\lambda^3 -3\lambda^2 -17\lambda -11$$
Taking $A=2X^2 + X$ in $p$ gives 
$$p(A) = -8X^6 - 12X^5 -18X^4 -13X^3 - 37X^2 - 17X - 11 = 0$$
Note that in particular,
$$q(x) = -8x^6 - 12x^5 -18x^4 -13x^3 - 37x^2 - 17x - 11 = 0$$
is an annihilating polynomial of $X$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $X$ must be amongst the roots of $q$. But all of $q$'s roots are complex, a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain to me why it wrong to assume matrices A, B and C as in the first answer and then show that matrix $b^2 - 4AC$ has a negative determinant?

Comment: The answer is a bit unclear but I don't think checking the determinant is what is intended. Rather Elias was trying to find the square root of the matrix (to solve the quadratic equation), which isn't always well defined.

Comment: Aha. But if I proved that the above mentioned matrix has negative determinant, it would give me the needed contradiction, wouldn't it?

Comment: You first have to note that $A,\ B$ and $C$ defined in Elias' answer all necessarily commute with $X$. That is crucial to the argument. With this in mind, then yes, proving that the "discriminant" has a negative determinant will show that there are no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A = \pmatrix{-1 & 5 & 3\cr -2 & 1 & 2\cr 0 & -4 & 3\cr}$ is equal to a polynomial is $X$, it commutes with $X$.  Now $0 = 2 X^2+ X - A = 2 (X + I/4)^2 - I/8 - A$.
Now $A$ has a simple  eigenvalue $\lambda \approx -.715923208$.  If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for this eigenvalue, it is also an eigenvector of $X$ for eigenvalue $\mu$, where $2 (\mu + 1/4)^2 = 1/8 + \lambda$.  But since $1/8 + \lambda < 0$, $\mu$ can't be real.  Now $v$ can be taken to be real (since $A$ and $\lambda$ are real), 
so $X v = \mu v$ is impossible if $X$ is real.